# Draggable & sortable widget define settings inline

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/) tutorial but I would like to define the `widgetIndividual` setting inline on individual pages. How can I do this. Whenever I try to add it inline it doesn't work. 
Example below:

```
$(function(){
    draggableWidgets.init({

        widgetIndividual : {
            intro : {
                movable: false,
                removable: false,
                collapsible: false,
                editable: false
            }
        }                                             
    });     
});
```